# Medir distância de vários pontos usando o Google

Tags: php, mysql, web-service, google-maps, geolocalização

Estou trabalhando em um app onde o usuário pode ver os estabelecimentos mais próximos dele.

No banco eu guardo a `latitude` e a `longitude`, e no mobile recupero a posição do usuário.

Eu fiz um `LIMIT` no SQL para trazer paginado esses dados ordenando pela menor distância. Para isso eu fiz o uso de um algoritmo para calcular esses pontos.

Porém o cliente me informou que a distância informada no app e a distância no `google maps` não são exatas. Analisando verifiquei que o Google faz o calculo baseado nas rotas.

Como eu poderia fazer para cruzar esses dados usando alguma API do google mantendo minha ordenação que está em SQL?

Já pensei em colocar no banco uma coluna e ir atualizando mas são muitos dados para eu ficar chamando um web-service. Alguém conhece alguma solução para resolver esse "problema"?

Comment: Vc quer a distância baseada na rota ou a distância entre 2 pontos "GPS" (entao, linha reita) ou seja, um query tipo "eu quero todas as lojas que estao a menos de 350m do meu ponto de ref." ?

Comment: Olá Peter eu consegui resolver... Estava bem no inicio do projeto, mas era distância de pontos mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo se foi resolvido, aqui uma função SQL que eu uso para calcular distancia entre pontos.

```
NO SQL
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN RETURN FLOOR(1000*(6371*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((src_lagps - dest_lagps)*pi()/180/2),2) + COS(src_lagps * pi()/180)*COS(dest_lagps*pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((src_logps - dest_logps)*pi()/180/2),2))))); 
END
```

Os parametros: src_lagps, src_logps, dest_lagps e dest_logps são do tipo float. O resultado é a distancia em metro.

Exemplo:

```
$query_select = "SELECT 
calcul_distance (".$lagps_usuario.",".$logps_usuario.",tloja_lagps,tloja_logps) as tloja_distancia,
tloja_id,
tloja_nom
FROM TAB_LOJA

HAVING tloja_distancia < ".$distancia_maxima." ORDER BY tloja_distancia";
```

Anota que vc deve usar "HAVING" e não "SELECT".

Answer (score 0):

Faz tempo que trabalhei com esse tipo de cálculo, mas quando fiz, utilizei o [Google Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=pt-br).

Com ele é possível você definir algumas métricas para fazer esse cálculo, como o modo de transporte (carro, andando, metrô, etc.) ou restrições de rota (evitar avenidas, etc.).

O que eu gostei bastante quando utilizei foi a opção de utilizar tanto coordenadas (Lat,Lng) como endereços (desde que válidos). Como eu não uso faz um tempo não sei se mudou, mas era possível definir apenas uma origem e alguns destinos, então é só você conciliar os dois dados (distância e sua ordem) para exibir os melhores resultados.

> Obs.: Eu precisei habilitar o acesso à essa API dentro do Google Developers Console.